# Get image from REST api with cURL

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

Here is th
    $picture = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject it straight into the html like that you will need two files one with the html and one with the image something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='getimage.php' />
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `getimage.php` file:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer xxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Display the image in the browser
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $picture;
?>
```

The only way you could do it in the same file would be to get the image and not change the header of the document and do a base64 encode of the image and use that as the src. It would be something like this I believe:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer xxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($picture); ?>" >
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you think I'll have to convert from the binary data to base64 in the image tag?

Comment: Thanks again, trying to get the first solution working currently but it still shows up as a broken picture. Are there any good debugging tools you know of for what might be going on?

Comment: If I had to guess if you look at the beginning of your image data it says `�PNG  IHDR����` my guess is it is a png image not a jpg. So I would change all references to png instead of jpg or jpeg.

Comment: still looks like a broken image :/ 

I just want to confirm though as you said in the response, is the     <img src='getimage.php' /> sufficient to handle the $picture?

Comment: Yes it should be. Not sure what the issue is then. You should be able to go straight to getimage.php in your browser and see the image by itself.

Comment: So i'm very close. Here is what I have so far. At the end of my getimage.php file, I have     echo base64_encode($picture);
 which gives me a huge base64 encoded string. Then im trying to put it in my main.html file with the line <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{binary data}" />

What do I replace {binary data} with to get the "echo" from the getimage.php file? Sorry, kinda noobish question

Comment: No don't combine the two either use the 2 file approach or use the base64 single file approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56151/discussion-between-canaan-linder-and-pitchinnate).